# Windows NDIS driver profiling

Tags: windows, performance, device-driver

I am working on performance profiling NDIS filter driver on Windows 10. I am using Windows Performance Recorder (WPR) and Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA) for this purpose. I am able to see the CPU usage graphs for processes but I am interested in load points in the driver code, which I am not able to get. It might be because I am not using the tools appropriately. Is there any guide or tutorial which can help me use these tools to get the desired results? My objective is to get a similar report like Oprofile in Linux.

Can someone suggest me whether WPR/WPA are the right tools that I am using? Is there any other better tool which can be more appropriate for my requirement?