# Profiling NDIS filter driver contention

Tags: windows, performance, networking, ndis, filter-driver

**Preface**

I am struggling with Windows 10 (Pro) network performance. Even when using registered IO (RIO) its not possible to receive more than 300k UDP packets per second in a stable manner - and this number can only be achieved when using multiple ports to spread the load onto multiple RSS queues under perfect lab conditions. I have posted related problem statements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66144818/has-winsock-registered-io-performance-degraded-since-2012) and in some [Microsoft forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/268716/has-winsock-registered-io-performance-degraded-sin.html). Keep in mind that they are somewhat older and make RIO (or my use of it) responsible for the observed problems (which it is not, as it seems). I even used a [tool from Microsoft itself](https://github.com/microsoft/ctsTraffic/issues) resulting in even worse performance than my own code.

**Question**

The [post in the Microsoft forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/268716/has-winsock-registered-io-performance-degraded-sin.html) (from MattJames-8087) resulted in an interesting comment which hints at filter driver level contention: "QoS and the component responsible for providing traffic filtering services". Unfortunately I did not get an answer to how I would be able to check if I am suffering from the same Problem. I found a [somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643603/windows-ndis-driver-profiling) but its unanswered and also is not interested in the *contention* part of my question. I therefore would appreciate hints on where to start reading about how I could profile this issue or rule it out altogether.

Thanks

Comment: It's easy enough to rule out QOS - just stop it and see if perf has changed: `net stop psched`

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.